# Exception in finding driving distance between two geopiont

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to find out driving distance between two latitude and longitude.
this is my code

```
private String GetDistance(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + ","
                + origin.longitude;
        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;
        // Output format
        String output = "json";
        // Building the url to the web service
        String urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + parameters;

        // get the JSON And parse it to get the directions data.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inStream));

            String temp,response = "";
            while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Parse data
                response += temp;
            }
            // Close the reader, stream & connection
            bReader.close();
            inStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();

            // Sort out JSONresponse
        //  JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
        //          .nextValue();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("routes");
            // Log.d("JSON","array: "+array.toString());

            // Routes is a combination of objects and arrays
            JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
            // Log.d("JSON","routes: "+routes.toString());

            String summary = routes.getString("summary");
             Log.d("JSON","summary: "+summary);

            JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
            // Log.d("JSON","legs: "+legs.toString());

            JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
            // Log.d("JSON","steps: "+steps.toString());

            JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
            // Log.d("JSON","distance: "+distance.toString());

            sDistance = distance.getString("text");
            iDistance = distance.getInt("value");  

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return e.toString();
        }

        return sDistance;
    }
```

and i am getting a exception

```
org.json.JSONException:Index 0 out of range [0..0)
```

this is my stacktrace

```
Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@41019be8
```

please help me out what is the problem.

Comment: In most cases, you will just need to go through the exception stacktrace and you could easily figure out what went wrong. If you are not able to do that, post the trace here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **don't hardcode** any position(like 0) to get from array. Bcs, the *array may be empty*.

That's what happened in your case. One of your `array` or `legs` **JSONArray is empty** but you are trying to get the 0th position of them. So,it is throwing index out of range exception.

To get the values from an array better use for loop. An example code snippet is:

```
Log.v("array-length--", ""+array.length());

for(int i=0; i < array.length();i++)
{
    // Routes is a combination of objects and arrays
    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(i);
    // Log.d("JSON","routes: "+routes.toString());

    String summary = routes.getString("summary");
    Log.d("JSON","summary: "+summary);

    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
    // Log.d("JSON","legs: "+legs.toString());

    Log.v("legs-length--", ""+legs.length());

    for(int j=0; j < legs.length(); j++)
    {
        JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(j);
        // Log.d("JSON","steps: "+steps.toString());

        JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
        // Log.d("JSON","distance: "+distance.toString());

        sDistance = distance.getString("text");
        iDistance = distance.getInt("value"); 
    }

}
```